# Responsive css not working on smartphone but working on resizing browser

Tags: css, responsive-design

I don't get it: I think I have built my css in a resposive way so it's restructures when viewed in a smartphone. It works when resizing browser page. It doesn't when checking on chrome tool developper and my Nexus 5 chrome browser. Website is www.peresola.com/index.html. Css responsive part below:

```css
@media (max-width:700px) {
  body {
    font-size:18px;
    
  }
  
    .menu li {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  
  p {
    font-size:18px;
    width:75%;
    margin:10px auto;
  }
  
  .personPage {
    height:30%;
    width:30%;
  }
  

  
  .socialIcons li img {
    height:50px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  input {
    padding:5px;
    font-size:15px;
  }
  
  .footer {
    font-size:10px;
  }
}
```

Note that I moved it from 500 to 700 to test it out today. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: do you have viewport? I think you don't, your code look fine.

Comment: @AleshaOleg Indeed, the viewport meta tag seems to be missing.

Comment: you guys are right! Didn't have the viewport in the html. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have viewport, add this one `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your `<head>` tag